# vba change event user types date

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help. I would like to fire off a msg whenever the user types in a date that is not within the dates approved.  The dates approved are in cell W12 and W13. the user inputs the date on cell N13 below is my code

```
Sub ErrorValidation_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$N$13" Then
        If target.Value > Range("W12") And target.Value < Range("W13") Then
        MsgBox "Date should be around" & Range("w12")
    Else
    do nothing
    End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What help do you need?  You haven't specified what the problem is?

Comment: sorry my code is not working. Am i missing something?

Comment: You need to comment out the `do nothing` line. Edit - you could delete the `Else:do nothing` rows.

Comment: You should also probably check that the user has actually entered a date as you might have an issue when someone types in "tomorrow"...

Comment: Just noticed - are you calling this procedure from an event such as `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`?  Either that, or place the code within a worksheet module in the change event.

Comment: @dave  the user is inputting a correct date. and i have commented out do nothing however the code is still not working

Comment: Have you changed the sub from `Worksheet_Change` to `ErrorValidation_Change`?  Try changing that back, and remember that this code must be in the relevant worksheet rather than `ThisWorkbook` or in a code module.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i tried calling it private sub, public sub and sub all which did not work

Comment: @Dave i changed it to worksheet_change and the code is in the correct worksheet however still nothing

Comment: Step through (use F8) and check what `target.Address` is showing as?

Comment: Guys had it reversed. The do nothing should be where the message box is and vise versa. The code works now

Comment: Thank you Dave and DarrenBartrup-Cook for your help

Answer (score 0):

Below is the corrected working code....

```
Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Address = "$N$13" Then
    If target.Value > Range("W12") And target.Value < Range("W13") Then
    'do nothing
Else
MsgBox "Date should be around" & Range("w12")

End If
    End If
```

End Sub